# Does asynchronous HTTP request get killed when the parent thread exiting?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, nsurlconnection

I sent a asynchronous HTTP request by NSURLConnecion on a background thread, the thread finished immediately after it post the request.
And I can't receive any response or error, just like the request disappeared.
But if I keep the thread running, then I can receive response fine.

Dose asynchronous HTTP request get killed automatically when the parent thread exiting?

Comment: how do you send your synchronous request? Do u use sendSynchronousRequest?

Comment: Sorry for the egregious typo! The correct is asynchronous request.

Comment: why forking a new thread just to send an asynchronous request? Since is asynchronous it will be anyway executed in a different thread.

Comment: Because the scene getting changed after the request sent, the delegate scene should be destroyed when the downloading complete.